# Firebase | Getting error on fetching RemoteConfig values on functions.pubsub.schedule onRun

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-remote-config

Normally we can fetch data from RemoteConfig normally in Firestore document triggers but in Pubsub schedule listener below code getting error:

let config = admin.remoteConfig();
const template = await config.getTemplate();

Error: Version update time must be a valid date string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved on firebase-admin 9.6.0 version or above.